# Starlight spotlights w/ volume help

Tags: lighting, volumetrics

I'm trying to create something similar to this image's sky-box.

[image]

I tried cutting holes into a plane and shining a spotlight through. My attempts end up with the light hitting the ground (which I don't want to happen in the majority of the time, nor where the "god rays" visible in my render image (beginner with volume settings)

Comment: Try decreasing the point light's emission value .Are you using  volumetric lighting?

Answer (score 4):

*There is several ways to get this effect ... but in your example are mixed two light effects. One is vertical lights from stars and second light scattering fromcentral light source. So here are some tips.*

### SunBeam (postpro)

- enable *Compositor*
- use *SunBeam* node with high Y value to get effect of light comming from top
- it depence on image, but sometimes you will need to do a pass for stars if there is some another bright source of light (or for masking reason foreground-background)

[image]
[image]
[image]

### Glare (postpro)

similar way is to use Glare node > Streaks > 2

[image]

### Volumetric

For light scattering

- add *Cube* with *Principled Volume* shader

[image]
[image]

For vertical light rays comming from top you can use Volumetric material, but without connection with stars on sky.

- use *2D Noise* texture node for vertical rays
- add *Areal* light on top

[image]

Comment: I used the Sun Beams, made two render layers, and now am using alphaover to put them together. BUT the sun beams disappear after the alpha over node. How do I keep the sunbeams when bringing both of the layers together? ![Nodes](https://imgur.com/a/cVdIalV)

Comment: Your node tree works as expected https://imgur.com/lo1B2AW for me. If you want SunBeams in front https://imgur.com/Wcc6aKu ... I'm not still sure if the effect should be lens flare or light scatter, it make difference in appearance in space. You would probably need Z-Combine node for more complex merge. Please share a screen with your issue.